# PHP Script to auto login and show page

Tags: php, authentication, curl

I have a web directory on my server that is password protected. The directory contains a load of html pages (A sort of help file) that I want to link to from my desktop application.

I want a user of my desktop application to be able to click a button in the app and see the password protected pages without having to enter the username and password in the dialogue box. The link will be something like www.mywebsite.com/seehiddenhelp.php?token=12345

If a valid token is passed (I already have this bit sorted) I want the php script to auto log them in and show the webpage i specify.

I think i need to use cURL to do this but I cannot figure out how to do it!

So far I have got: (By the way I have taken out the token validation bit and just replaced it with a case!)

```
<?php 

$token = $_GET["token"];

switch ($token) {
    case "ValidToken":
        $url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/protected/index.html";
        $username = "username";
        $password = "password";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);  
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

    break;

    }


?>
```

When I go to www.mywebsite.com/seehiddenhelp.php?token=12345 It just shows a blank page, no errors or anything just a blank page and the token stays in the url bar. Ideally I want it to login then show the page i specify with that url in the address bar.

I guess what is happening is that it is getting the contense of the file but not doing anything with it? How do I display it on the screen or redirect to it?

Any help would be much appreciated! Sorry if its a simple lack of understanding on my part but i have tried to find the solution for ages now!

**EDIT:**

I have had more success with the following code:

```html
       //Variables
  $target_url = "http://www.Mywebsite/secure/index.html";
  $username = "username";
  $password = "password";

//Contains encoded string to pass along for basic authentication purposes 
$auth_token = base64_encode($username . '-' . $password);

//Create a new cURL handle 
$ch = curl_init($target_url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);

$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);

$response_data = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response_data;

if (curl_errno($ch)> 0){
die('There was a cURL error: ' . curl_error($ch));
} else {
//Close the handler and release resources
curl_close($ch);
}
```

It appears to sort of work as the page uses frames, the frames are shown at the top and bottom but the pages inside the frames show 404 pages? I think I am getting closer but still not got a clue!

**EDIT 2**

With the second code sample I changed the code on the index page so the url loaded into the frame was the full url, not just toc.html, which would be local. It then shows a login box in the frame page which if canceled shows a 401 so my issue is, the curl settings are not used by the pages loaded into the frame so i need a way of authenticating the main session not just the curl session which is used to render out the page. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: No errors; are you checking for them? Is your server setup to automatically check them for you and display them?

Comment: There is an error log in the script folder and nothing is written there when this script is run. If i put a typo in it shows in the error log. I am not checking anywhere else for errors though. I dont usually write PHP so forgive my ignorance!

Comment: Have you tried printing the value of $URL so you can view it? It may also be that the server disallows blatant scripted access. You will need to make your script masquerade as something like IE.

Comment: I wasn't inferring ignorance. I merely asked if it was set/working.

Comment: I am a winforms developer so feel a bit out of my depth with this one Fred! kainaw, do you mean pass in the user agent to the curl?

Comment: I understand Chris. Now, the only reason I could see your comment, is because I've kept this tab open, seeing if any progress has been made. If you wish Kainaw to be notified, use the `@` symbol followed by their name. I won't be able to offer further help, since I don't know enough about CURL, but rather let people know how to check for errors in PHP. Good luck, I hope this gets resolved, *cheers!*

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii I was wondering how you tag people! Thanks for your assistance, hopefully someone else may be able to offer some advice. I suspect it may be something to do with the cookies as its showing the main page ok but not the pages in the frame which im guessing either are not  authenticating properly or maybe they need to use the full path names?

Comment: You're welcome @ChrisSmith ;-) Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. May help, *cheers*